# Video format needed for device/tablet application

Tags: android, video

We are trying to produce videos for an Android app ( Devices, Tablets, Nook & Kindle) We have a problem since we dont know which resolutions to use. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html they recomend to produce just 3 video sizes. Its Ok for the video & audio codec bitrate. But we are not sure about sizes & resolutions since there are many more devices screens aspect ratio

We **dont want to deform** the videos but we are not sure about which are the final resolutions & sizes we need to produce the videos in order to show them correctly in all Android Devices/Tablets.

Is there any one can help us with this issue?

Comment: [This](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/12/size-really-does-matter-common-tablet-resolutions-compared/) might help. Since you don't want to deform the videos you would probably have to letterbox or crop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the article but I need other kind of information. I don't need the size aspect ratio of several device screens, what I need is an average video format values (an average weight) to fit well in most of the Android devices. I mean, for example, 3 or 4 standard video format values.